# The Best of 2021!

Tags: discussion

So, it's the last day of 2021, time to look back and see the highest scored *things* on the site this year!

There are no prizes, just this commemorative post that you could, if you want the pride, print and stick to your wall. We won't judge.

---

## Best Comment of 2021

### #3

At #3 we have a tie at 28 upvotes, and both are on the same post, talking about how a control scheme is similar to launching a nuke! Thanks to @Thomas Weller and @Xan for this apt comparison!

**[How to end the game in 2-player Lemmings (Super Nintendo), with no "Nuke" option?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/387728/how-to-end-the-game-in-2-player-lemmings-super-nintendo-with-no-nuke-option/387729#comment546507_387729)**

### #2

At #2, edging out #3 by only one vote (29), we have @SF. that gives a few explanations about what is an Any% speedrun.

**[What is an any % speed run in Diablo 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/382603/what-is-an-any-speed-run-in-diablo-2/382604#comment537803_382604)**

### #1

And at #1, we got a comment that demolished any other comment on the website this year with 50 (!) upvotes. Its adding a 50 minute explanation video to an answer about one of the biggest news story in gaming, Dream's Minecraft Speedrun. Congratulations to @luk2302, seems lots of users loved to hear this more detailed explanation to the dream problem.

**[How was it calculated that Dream cheated on his Minecraft v1.16 glitchless speedrun?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/386685/how-was-it-calculated-that-dream-cheated-on-his-minecraft-v1-16-glitchless-speed/386687#comment545096_386687)**

*If you want to see more comments, [see the query that gave the results](https://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/revision/1539858/1883839/best-of-the-year-comment).*

---

## Best Question of 2021

### #3

At #3 we got, at 49 score, @BrapPleaseHelp asking **[Is there a way to hide that you own a game in the steam store?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/380440/is-there-a-way-to-hide-that-you-own-a-game-in-the-steam-store)**. We don't know that you wanted to hide, but now lots of people know you want to hide something! :p

### #2

At #2, we got the question that created our #3 comment with 51 score, **[How to end the game in 2-player Lemmings (Super Nintendo), with no "Nuke" option?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/387728/how-to-end-the-game-in-2-player-lemmings-super-nintendo-with-no-nuke-option)** Hope your Lemmings decimating needs were fulfilled @LHM!

### #1

And at #1, we got @RedFlame0627 asking **[Where did the Goombas come from?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/386486/where-did-the-goombas-come-from)** Did you switch from button mushrooms to shiitake mushrooms in your cooking since?

*If you want to see more questions, [see the query that gave the results](https://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/revision/1539856/1883837/best-of-the-year-question).*

---

## Best Answer from 2021

### #3

At #3, we got @Chengarda giving a great and quick explanation of what is a skinner box. Its a great read to know how loot boxes are made to make you spend more in videogames. Those 78 upvotes are well deserved!

**[What does it mean for a game to be a skinner box?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/385616/what-does-it-mean-for-a-game-to-be-a-skinner-box/385648#385648)**

### #2

At #2, we have @Paul Z coming in with his insider knowledge to help exorcise an Xbox. 92 upvotes is a great score to keep demons our of our consoles!

**[Xbox "Screenshot uploaded" notification looked like a demon had possessed my Xbox, what could the reason be?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/386195/xbox-screenshot-uploaded-notification-looked-like-a-demon-had-possessed-my-xbo/386200#386200)**

### #1

And at #1, we have @Joshua Bizley cracking the 100 score bar with a score of 101 by coming to the rescue of a user that seemingly lost his whole Steam Library! Sure that user got back his library, but he didn't tell.

**[I reset my laptop and now Steam games are all missing](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/385181/i-reset-my-laptop-and-now-steam-games-are-all-missing/385182#385182)**

*If you want to see more answers, [see the query that gave the results](https://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/revision/1539854/1883835/best-of-the-year-answer).*

---

## Best User of 2021

Now, this is not the greatest users, but those who raked in the most rep this year. So that means people that always came back with great questions and answers, day after day.

### #3 - @PausePause with +4,359 reputation in 2021

### #2 - @SF. with +5,322 reputation in 2021

### #1 - @pinckerman with +7,359 reputation in 2021

*You can see the full statistics [here](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/41/year/gaming)*

---

So today we say goodbye to 2021, and tomorrow, onto 2022. We, the team of mods, hope for you to all have a happy new year! See you in 2022!

Comment: What a great year it was! I won "screenshot of the week" twice and then this. Hey mum, look, I'm famous now!

Comment: I would say of anyone can think of any other "best of" _things_, you can write your own answer on this post!

Comment: @TimmyJim best stack? Arqade ;)

Comment: Nice post! Thanks Fredy!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Best of Site Analytics for 2021

##### Traffic:

- Day with most page views: January 1<sup>st</sup> (362,590 views)
- Day with the most site visits: January 2<sup>nd</sup> (317,506 visits)
- Day with the most new visits: January 1<sup>st</sup> (183,001 new visits)

[image: traffic]

#### Voting:

- Day with most accept votes: February 23<sup>rd</sup> (22 accept votes)
- Day with most up/down votes: January 7<sup>th</sup> (307 votes)
- Day with most up votes: January 7<sup>th</sup> (274 votes)
- Day with most down votes: March 8<sup>th</sup> (66 votes)

[image: votes]

#### Posts:

- Day with most questions: January 20<sup>th</sup> (31 questions)
- Day with most answers: January 20<sup>th</sup> & March 8<sup>th</sup> (48 on each day)
- Day with most questions and answers: January 20<sup>th</sup> (79)

[image: posts]

Comment: Wow, that's interesting Jan is the most popular month. Probably people are figuring out how to play games/consoles they got during holidays

Answer (score 7):

## Winter/Summer Bash 2021 Results

**546** Arqade users have earned a total of **769** hats!

Top 3 (or rather 5) hat collectors:

[image]

You can see full leaderboard [here](https://winterbash2021.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/gaming.stackexchange.com)

Comment: That sounds like relatively few hats  (also, it seems I just didn't make the list..).

Comment: @Joachim It probably seems relatively low because, as seen on the [network-wide](https://winterbash2021.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network) statistics, the person with the highest number of hats has some that would be fairly difficult to achieve on Arqade alone. Some being "Write 10 good answers in one day" or "Have five of your answers accepted in one day"

Comment: I actually thought a lot of the hats were difficult in general this year to try and obtain.

Comment: Yeah, and of course I had my total amount of (unique) hats from all over the network in mind. But I think I also expected more users with hats on a relatively large site like Arqade.